# Is there any valid way to show an input without a border in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a SAPUI5 app in which we do not want to add custom css to. Currently we are displaying text in a form which does not have the same height and styling as the inputs.

I'd prefer to change the text to an input with a pre-filled value so everything in the form has consistent styling but I need to differentiate that this should be treated as text.

The easiest way to do this is to remove the border but I cannot find away of doing this without creating custom css.

I tried `borderDesign="None"` but this does not affect inputs.

Comment: You can achieve it by using [jQuery css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: how about setting the input element to enabled="false". still a border but a consistent form in look and feel

Comment: What's so wrong with custom CSS? It's the very tool to solve your problem

Comment: Using custom CSS is not bad per se. In your case it seems valid. Just give your Input a custom CSS class and don't overwrite SAP standard classes.

Comment: Custom CSS is your solution. There is no SAP standard class to disable borders. As @Marc said, just write a class with your custom name avoiding overwriting standard classes and it will comply with SAP best practices.

Comment: i agree with @n01dea here. Look up the FIORI Designguidelines for more info:  https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/input-field/#editable-and-enabled-states1